# How to print Photoshop file document to only one color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, print-design

Is there any way of converting a Photoshop file with text and logos to one only. I want to print to only one color.

Comment: You can convert any Photoshop file to greyscale, which is one color, then print. I have a feeling you need to describe your file rather than ask if you can convert it to one color in every application.

Comment: I think there's rather more to this. Are you talking about desktop printing or printing press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Image > Mode > Greyscale

Or a better way -- Image > Adjustments > Black and White (Tweak to your liking) Click Okay. Then Image > Mode > Greyscale.

Then Print.

Comment: I like your second way much better. If something other than black is wanted, you can check the Tint box in the BW layer and assign a color there.

Comment: It's a bit more involved if you want to print as a spot colour though.

Comment: @e100 not if it's just one color. You can set it as black and just indicate the spot color to use on press.

Comment: This is true, but if it's going to be included in an InDesign doc and sent as PDF I'd prefer it to be tagged with the relevant spot colour.